# How to detect in Page_Unload, that an unhandled exception has occured already?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

Page_Unload is called even if an unhandled exception has occurred. I need to deal with that situation.

I have a variable state validation throwing an exception when the variable is not in correct state in Page_Unload. The exception is later on processed by `Application_Error` in `Global.asax`. I need to suppress throwing an exception when another exception has already occurred.

The page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int tst = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tst = tst / tst; //causes "Attempted to divide by zero."
        tst = 1;
    }
    protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tst == 0) throw new Exception("Exception on unload"); 
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the error details
    Exception lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(lastErrorWrapper.Message);
}
```

I need to get *"Attempted to divide by zero."* in `Global.asax` but I am getting *"Exception on unload"*

The example given is drastically simplified. The real situation includes a user control and a conditional compilation.

I am not allowed solve the situation in `Page_Load` (e.g. by catching the exception).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use global.asax method like this

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            // Get the error details
            Exception lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError();            
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(lastErrorWrapper.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx?q=" + lastErrorWrapper.Message);
        }
```

Then it wont show the error here, alternate is:

set custom error page in web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mypage.aspx">   
    </customErrors>
```

Regards

Comment: I use it this way in the real application. The code presented is a simplified example only. But it does not solves the problem - getting the different message than thrown.

Comment: then a better example is needed preferably with a control and actual data/exception @IvanH

Comment: The problem is either to suppress throwing in Page_Unload or somehow get "previous exception" in Application_Error. An occurring exception is unknown. If I had known the exception I would have prevent it instead of showing it.

Comment: alright maybe this should be of help to you http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/unhandled.aspx

Comment: plus do you need the page_unload method cause if thats the case then you are not going t get the "exception cause" ,the method will always run and will reset any exception you get from load method, if you dont use it you can see the exception in lastErrorWrapper.InnerException. Hope that helps you @IvanH

Comment: I have tested AppDomain.UnhandledException (from  thescarms...) but I have not manage to get it working. It seems to work in desktop application only. Yes, removing Page_Unload suppresses exception overwriting, but I need a solution for Page_Unload included. Maybe the question should have been: 'How to modify Page_Unload not to throw the exception when other exception has been thrown in Page_Load?' Is it more clear now?